# Javascript doesn't let me get the value of object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I clearly see the object `o` is an object with `source` and `source` has `color` property, using `console.log(o)`, but when I try to take this `color` value, I get `undefined`. Why on earth??????

So I do:

```
console.dir(d);
```

and I see:

```
Object
    source
        color: "#90eb9d"
```

but then I do:

```
console.log(d.source.color);
```

and I get `undefined`.

Comment: Show us some code, maybe we can help then...

Comment: I would be checking where the `source` object comes from. you are probably trying to access the property before it's value has been initialized.

Comment: @L.Yogev yes but I clearly see the value in the console.

Comment: @Vladimir Despotovic What you are seeing in the console is the final value not the value at that point.

Comment: Output on the console might be misleading, as the object is only being resolved after clicking on 'expand' , and might not be at the same state of when you console.log'd it

Comment: so ...... how do I get this value../...I have to work around this? I actually cannot get it here then? Is this the point?  I assume so.